# Changing font family of lstlisting to standard/normal LaTex font

Tags: fonts, listings

I want to change the font family of my lstlisting to an italicized "normal" latex font, so a non-monospaced font. I've already tried setting my `basicstyle=\rmfamily\itshape` and while it makes the text italic the font family didn't change, its still in the monospace style font.

```
\lstset{emph={OR, AND},emphstyle=\textbf}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My caption},label={search_string}, captionpos=b, basicstyle=\rmfamily\itshape]
        cars AND (items OR accessories)
\end{lstlisting}
```

It gives me:

[image]

While I want it to be:

[image]

However I would like to use a listing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font family did change. You can try `\sffamily` to verify this.  However, the listing was still being displayed with fixed columns.  Give it `columns=fullflexible` to switch them off.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{emph={OR, AND},emphstyle=\textbf}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My caption},
                   label={search_string},
                   captionpos=b,
                   basicstyle=\rmfamily\itshape,
                   columns=fullflexible]
        cars AND (items OR accessories)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern sample]

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot!